# Asynchronous controller AND Ajax request

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I have an asynchronous controller,
I know the action will work asynchronously (no other action wait for that) and returns after completion of the task.

So my question is how it is deferent from making an asynchronous Ajax request to an action.
I think both are same in result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An async request from javascript is not the same as an async task on the server.

An async task from javascript is still processed synchronously on the server, and as such, you may encounter thread pool starvation on large applications.

Having an async request that is processed asynchronously on the server is different, it frees up the IIS thread to immediately process other requests while that request, either from javascript or a full post/get is processed in the background.

some reading may help

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598(v=vs.98).aspx#processing_asynchronous_requests](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728598%28v=vs.98%29.aspx#processing_asynchronous_requests)